# ionic2 tabs overflow on an iphone 5

Tags: ionic2

When I run 5 tabs on an ionic 2 app in an iphone 5s emulator, it has wide margins between the icons and it cuts off the first and last icon off screen.  It looks fine on the browser set to a smaller screen width so it looks like it should fit.  It also looks fine on an iphone 6 emulator.  Is this a bug in the ionic 2 beta css?

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabFavesRoot" tabTitle="Faves" tabIcon="heart"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabPeopleRoot" tabTitle="People" tabIcon="people"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabHostGameRoot" tabTitle="Create" tabIcon="add-circle"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabMessagesRoot" tabTitle="Messages" tabIcon="chatbubbles"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tabMyProfileRoot" tabTitle="My Profile" tabIcon="person"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```